# unable to execute multiple tags in Cucumber 6.9.1 version

Tags: cucumber-jvm

@RunWith(Cucumber.class)

@CucumberOptions(

features="src/test/java/featurefiles",

plugin="json:target/jsonReports/cucumber-maven-report.json",

glue={"com.xcarrier.stepdefinition"},

tags="@CarrierShip and @PB_USPS_Ship")

public class TestRunner
{

}

Comment: If you want scenarios tagged with either one, you need to use `or`.

Comment: If I am using ' or ' condition in tags it is working. Whereas ' and ' is not working. Also tags="@CarrierShip, @Rate" is not working